# Como puedo saber que atributos o métodos tiene un objeto en c++

Tags: c++, c, clase

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de conocer los métodos y atributos de un objeto en C/C++

Ejemplo:

```
class Persona {
   char* name;
public:
   void hablar();
};
```

Si tengo una clase `Persona`, creo una instancia `Persona person();` y quiero saber que métodos y atributos tiene, ¿cómo lo hago?

Comment: Si usas visual studio pones un punto y automáticamente te aparece una lista de posibles opciones para autocompletar.

Answer (score 1):

Si buscas una forma *manual*, la solución pasa por ir a la cabecera de la clase y analizar su interfaz. Eventualmente tendrás que acudir también a las clases padre.

Esta misma información la puedes obtener de forma estática vía [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org). Al ejecutar este programa se generarán una serie de páginas web con la información y documentación de las clases que encuentre.

La última forma, y posiblemente la que estás buscando, es dependiente del IDE y se trata de un algoritmo que inspecciona el proyecto y va generando una serie de mapas que te indican, de forma visual, información interesante en tiempo real:

- Nombre de las clases
- Firma de los métodos de las clases y funciones sueltas
- Tipo de las variables

En el caso de Visual Studio, este algoritmo se llama *intellisense*.

[image: Intellisense en acción]

Sin embargo esta característica no es exclusiva de VS. Otros IDEs han implementado utilidades similares como QtCreator, CodeBlocks, ...

Eso sí, para que esta utilidad funcione es necesario que configures correctamente el proyecto en el propio IDE, de esta forma el IDE sabrá dónde se encuentran los fuentes y podrá procesarlos convenientemente.